# Display text between 2 patterns in vbscript

Tags: regex, vbscript

I have a file that has this text:

```
         "Name": "running"
        "LaunchTime": "2015-02-13T20:20:11.000Z", 
        "InstanceId": "i-<something>", 
            "Name": "stopped"
        "LaunchTime": "2015-02-13T17:24:11.000Z", 
        "InstanceId": "i-<something>", 
            "Name": "stopped"
        "LaunchTime": "2015-02-12<some-text>", 
        "InstanceId": "i-<something>",
```

I wanted to display timestamp for running block, which would grab text between:
pattern1 = "running"
pattern2 = "000Z"
I have a hard time figuring this out and I've tried google and dozen of different combinations but because vbs is not my forte I ask anyone for help.

I have this code:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objRE = ObjectCreate ("VBScript.RegExp")
objRE.global = 1
objRE.Multiline = 1
objRE.IgnoreCase = 1



Set inFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\newresult2.txt", ForReading)
Set outFile = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\timestampB.txt", 2, True)


strResult = ""
objRE.Pattern = """running""((?:.|\n|\r)*?)Z"","

If objRE.Test(inFile) Then strResult = objRE.Execute(inFile).item(0).SubMatches.item(0)
WScript.Echo strResult


inFile.Close
outFile.Close
```

I can figure out how to write to the second file later but the regex is driving me nuts for last few days, so I'd appreciate anyone pointing me somewhere.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
"running"\s*(.*?)(?=0{3}Z)
```

Try this.Grab the group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eS7gD7/20

```
Dim strRegex as String = """running""\s*(.*?)(?=0{3}Z)"
Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim strTargetString As String = "        ""Name"": ""running""" & ChrW(10) & "        ""LaunchTime"": ""2015-02-13T20:20:11.000Z"", " & ChrW(10) & "        ""InstanceId"": ""i-<something>"", " & ChrW(10) & "            ""Name"": ""stopped""" & ChrW(10) & "        ""LaunchTime"": ""2015-02-13T17:24:11.000Z"", " & ChrW(10) & "        ""InstanceId"": ""i-<something>"", " & ChrW(10) & "            ""Name"": ""stopped""" & ChrW(10) & "        ""LaunchTime"": ""2015-02-12<some-text>"", " & ChrW(10) & "        ""InstanceId"": ""i-<something>"","

For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(strTargetString)
     If myMatch.Success Then
' Add your code here
  End If
Next
```